# How do I get growlnotify to show  a multiple-line message from the command line?

Tags: macos, growl, growlnotify

Using `growlnotify` how can I display multiple lines of text from the command line?

Slash-n - `\n` - like this doesn't seem to work:

```
growlnotify -t title -m "messageline1\nmessage2"
```

I just get a message `messageline1\nmessage2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended escaped newline is not interpreted as such by growl - it's just treated as a literal slash, followed by an 'en'.

You can get the shell to insert a newline in the string this way:

```
growlnotify -t title -m "messageline1"$'\n'"message2"
```

See (e.g.) *[Unix command sh](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sh.htm)*:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to
>   string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specifed by the
>   ANSI C standard.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier and much more readable in scripts to use a little function and `echo`'s `-e` option:

```
mynotify () {
    for m in "$@"; do
        local msg="$msg\n$m"
    done
    echo -e "$msg" | growlnotify -t "My Title"
}

mynotify "This is line 1" "Line 2" "The 3d line ends with an extra newline\n" "Line 4"
```